# Address removed on checkout in guest checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I have this problem in magento 1.9 with checkout one page.

In the checkout process when I select the guest checkout, complete the billing form and click continue,and after I go out in a category of the e-commerce because i forgot to add an item in the cart, I come back in the checkout to finish the process I must write another time the billing informations because the fields are empty. Is possible to add the informations only one time?

I found this article:http://www.samitrimal.com.np/magento-address-removed-on-checkout-in-guest-checkout/
should be a solution but i don't know how to implement, please can you help me?

thanks

Alberto

**Update**

I post here what i added in the system following the guide:

1) I created a folder inside App/etc/modules/**Fix_billing.xml**

inside the xml file there is:

```
<config>
<modules>
 <Fix_billing>
   <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
   </Fix_billing>
 </modules></config>
```

2) Another Folder in App/code/local/**Fix**/**billing**/
and after inside other folders:

Block
controllers
etc
Helper
Model
sql

inside **etc** folder I added config.xml with the code of the guide and inside the **controllers folder** a file IndexController.php with the code of the guide.

After all this what's my mistake? sorry but i the first time I di this  chenges..

Thanks
Alberto

Okay I tried but doesn't work, in this link I have all the data I inserted..please can you check if it's okay?

http://we.tl/SrfTX1gGdm

thanks Alberto

Comment: The link you posted looks promising.. what exactly you don't understand in the link? perhaps you are creating custom extension for the first time. in that case, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento.. 
so that you'll be familiar to Magento

Comment: I followed the guide, please if you can help me to understand where i did mistakes. I created in App/etc/module/Fix_billing.xml after I created the different folders in App/code/local/Fix/billing/  and inside there are the different folders, in etc folder i added config.xml and paste inside the code from the guide, after in controller folder I created IndexController.php and paste the second part of the code from the guide, it is  correct?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code and names of the files so that we all can help you to fix it.

Comment: Hi Raks.....news?

Comment: in your config.xml, <Fix_billing> should be changed to <Fix_Billing> Note the capital B

Comment: delete the cache after making the change and check again

Comment: Hi Rasks, have you check the files? are correct?

Comment: have you made the change: from <Fix_billing> to <Fix_Billing>?

Comment: yes, I did the change

Comment: in this link you can see all the files with the informations, http://we.tl/SrfTX1gGdm

Comment: Hi raks, is  correct all for you?

Comment: The link says "Sorry the download is not available any more"

Comment: new link for the download http://we.tl/36wOEv3vs4

Comment: Alberto, there's still lot to do in your code. To start, first place your code for BLOCK in Fix/Billing/Block. You have pasted that in your indexController.php